# create factor variable by hours of the day

Tags: r, datetime

I have observations for several days: three dates and continuous time (00:00:00 - 23:59:59) in the format "yyyy-mm-dd %H:%M:%S". I want to create categorical variable corresponding to 23 breaks (hours of day), i.e. 00:00-01:00, 01:00-02:00 ,..., 23:00-00:00. So that the datetime "yyyy-mm-dd 22:51:03" is converted to 22:00-23:00. `cut.POSIXct` gives breaks for hours of each day separately

```
cut.POSIXct(df$datetime, breaks = "hours", include.lowest = T) # factor variable of 69 levels
```

or breaks for days

```
cut.POSIXct(df$datetime, breaks = "days", include.lowest = T) # factor variable of 3 levels
```

How can I get factor variable of 23 levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `datetime` is already in `POSIXct` format, one way would be to extract the hours from each value, convert them to `factor` and then to `integer` so that you will have one level for each hour irrespective of the date.

```
df$level <- as.integer(factor(format(df$datetime, "%H")))
```

If `datetime` is not in `POSIXct` you might want to change it first

```
df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$datetime)
```